# Why is this the optimal value of the dual problem?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization

> Let the primal problem be to determine the feasibility of the system $f_0 =0, f_i(x) \le 0$ for $i=1, 2, \dots, m$ and
>    $h_i(x)=0$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, m$.
>
> The dual problem associated with this is to maximize $g(\lambda, v) =
>  \inf_{x \in D}(\lambda^Tf(x) + v^Th(x))$.
>
> The optimal value of the dual problem is given by
>
> $d^* =
> \begin{cases}
> \infty,  & \text{ if } \space\lambda \ge 0, g(\lambda, v)\gt 0 \text{ is feasible } \\[2ex]
> 0, & \text{ if } \space\lambda \ge 0, g(\lambda, v)\gt 0 \text{ is infeasible }
> \end{cases}$

Why is the optimal value of the dual problem given as $d^*$?  Why does $g(\lambda, v) \gt 0$ have to be feasible or infeasible?  Why can't we have $g(\lambda, v) \le 0$ in any situation?  If $g \lt 0$ then how can $d^*=0$?

Below is the full text from where this is taken.  From the book Convex Optimization.

---

[image]

Comment: Can you write the primal problem? It's not completely clear to me what it is.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok I understand the primal and your dual problem but it's not clear what you've written in brackets for $d^*$. In particular, both the conditions are the same?

Comment: I rewrote the conditions for clarity.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions but what do you mean by $g(\lambda, v) > 0$ is feasible? I haven't ever seen the problem written this way.

Comment: I have included a picture from the text to better explain the notation.

Comment: Feasibility of a problem means it has a solution that satisfies the inequalities and equalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (f_1(x), ..., f_m(x))$ and $h(x)=(h_1(x), ..., h_p(x))$. Let $D$ be a set.  The *primal problem* is to find $x \in D$ that satisfies $f(x)\leq 0, h(x)=0$. We say the primal problem is *feasible* if there is such an $x \in D$.

Define 
$$ M = \{(\lambda, v) : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m, v \in \mathbb{R}^p, \lambda \geq 0\}$$
The dual function $g(\lambda, v)$ should be maximized subject to the constraint $(\lambda, v) \in M$. Define $d^* = \sup_{(\lambda, v) \in M} g(\lambda, v)$. It is not difficult to show that 
$$d^* = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\infty &\mbox{ if the primal is not feasible } \\
0  & \mbox{ if the primal is feasible} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
So there are only two possibilities for $d^*$ (either $d^*=0$ or $d^*=\infty)$. 
It follows that if there is a $(\lambda, v) \in M$ such that $g(\lambda, v)>0$, then certainly the *supremum* of $g(\lambda, v)$ cannot be zero, so the supremum must be $\infty$. Conversely, if there is *no* $(\lambda, v) \in M$  such that $g(\lambda, v)>0$, then the supremum certainly cannot be $\infty$ and so the supremum must be $0$. Thus
$$ d^* = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\infty &\mbox{ if there is a $(\lambda, v) \in M$ such that $g(\lambda,v)>0$. } \\
0  & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
This is likely what the equation in your question means.

---

I agree with Tony S.F. comments that the way of writing $d^*$ in your question (which I think is equivalent to my "second way" of writing $d^*$ above) is a bit unusual.  However, in your cut-and-paste it seems the authors use the second way to prove the first way (not the other way round as I suggest above).

Actually it is not a bad way to prove it:  The authors observe:

- $(\lambda, v) \in M \implies (\alpha \lambda, \alpha v) \in M$ for any real number $\alpha \geq 0$.
- $g(\alpha \lambda, \alpha v) = \alpha g(\lambda, v)$ for any real number $\alpha \geq 0$.
- $(0,0) \in M$.

So if there is a $(\lambda, v) \in M$ such that $g(\lambda, v)>0$, we observe $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}g(\alpha\lambda, \alpha v)\rightarrow \infty$ and so $\sup_{(\lambda, v) \in M} g(\lambda, v) = \infty$. On the other hand if there is no $(\lambda, v) \in M$ for which $g(\lambda, v)>0$ then the supremum must be less than or equal to 0; The supremum cannot be negative because $g(0,0)=0$, and so the supremum must be 0.